# Using React Native Context To Update List In Search Bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-android

I have a search bar in my React Native app, without context implementation the list displayed properly. But when I implemented Context, the list was not displaying again, only the search bar was displaying, and when I type on the search bar I get this error message;  `ERROR  TypeError: item.indexOf is not a function. (In 'item.indexOf(str)', 'item.indexOf' is undefined)`
I know am missing something, but I don't know where am missing it. Please I need help to solve this issue. Below is my code:

```js
//....
//....
import songs from '../../SongData';

import styles from './styles';

const data = [songs];

const ListContext = React.createContext({
  list: [data],
  setList: () => {}
});

export const ListProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(data);

  return (
    <ListContext.Provider value={{list, setList}}>
      {children}
    </ListContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Item = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const Playerlist = () => {
    const [isDisabled, setisDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isPlayed, setIsPlayed] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState(songs);
    
    //....
    //.....
    
    const renderHeader = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const listContext = useContext(ListContext);

    const updateQuery = (str) => {
      listContext.setList(data.filter((item) => item.indexOf(str) > -1));
      setText(str);
    };

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          padding: 10,
          marginVertical: 10,
          borderRadius: 20
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          clearButtonMode="always"
          value={text}
          onChangeText={updateQuery}
          placeholder="Search songs"
          style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', paddingHorizontal: 20 }} 
        />
      </View>
    )
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Avatar
                source={{ uri: item.picture }}
                style={{ marginRight: 16 }} 
                size='giant'
          />
          <Text style={styles.title} category='s1'> {item.title} </Text>
        </View>
        <Text 
          style={{ 
            color: '#444',
            fontSize: 11, 
            marginLeft: 112, 
            marginVertical: -20, 
            bottom: 27 
          }}
          category='s1'
          >{item.ArtistName} 
        </Text>
        <Text 
          style={{ 
            color: '#999', 
            marginLeft: 110, 
            marginVertical: -20,
            top: 10
          }}
          category='s1'
          >Genre: {item.genre} 
        </Text>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', left: '230%', bottom: '7%'}}>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={()=>playSound(item, index)} 
                style={{padding: 10, top: 30, left: 30}}
              >
                <Ionicons name="play" color={isPlayed ? 'red' : '#555555'} size={22} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={()=>stopSound(index)} 
                style={{padding: 10, top: 30, left: 20}}
              >
                <Ionicons name="stop" color="#555555" size={22} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );



  const renderFooter = () => {
    if (!loading) return null

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                paddingVertical: 15,
                borderTopWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#CED0CE',
            }}
        >
            <ActivityIndicator animating size='large' />
        </View>
    );
  }

  const renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
        <View 
            style={{
                height: 1,
                width: '86%',
                backgroundColor: '#CED0CE',
                marginLeft: '5%',
            }}
        />
    )
  }



  return (
      <ListContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => (
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
              data={context.list}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(i, key) => 'item-' + key}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
              ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
              ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        )}
      </ListContext.Consumer>
      
  );
};
```

Here's SongData.js code:

```js
const songs = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Hero',
        ArtistName: 'Bethany Dilon',
        genre: 'pop',
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.18169-9/16195530_10211997136709517_8578854309931959016_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_eui2=AeEvt5zlNj1bM87SMIgRXz8VjFbfh8f8mfyMVt-Hx_yZ_ISR6pzt6j1tOqssNCwDfnM&_nc_ohc=oQeQeYLPRz8AX_n81Yh&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&oh=d87b3097c543a39067095bacfbeb004d&oe=609BF1DC',
        url: require('../../assets/songs/Hero.mp3'),
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Advertising URL',
        ArtistName: 'Bethany Dilon',
        genre: 'Soft Rock',
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url:
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zmxv/react-native-sound-demo/master/advertising.mp3',
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Stronger',
        ArtistName: 'Bethany Dilon',
        genre: 'Country',
        isRequire: true,
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url: require('../../assets/songs/Stronger.mp3'),
    },

    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Faded',
        ArtistName: 'Luchee',
        genre: 'Techno',
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url: 'https://github.com/ShivamJoker/sample-songs/raw/master/Faded.mp3',
    },

    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Solo',
        ArtistName: 'Solo Cosmos',
        genre: 'Afrobeat',
        isRequire: true,
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url: 'https://github.com/ShivamJoker/sample-songs/raw/master/Solo.mp3',
    },

    {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Death Bed',
        ArtistName: 'Omowunmi feat Wizkid',
        genre: 'Afrocentric',
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url: 'https://github.com/ShivamJoker/sample-songs/raw/master/death%20bed.mp3',
    },

    {
        id: 7,
        title: 'Hero',
        ArtistName: 'Bethany Dilon',
        genre: 'pop',
        isRequire: true,
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.18169-9/16195530_10211997136709517_8578854309931959016_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_eui2=AeEvt5zlNj1bM87SMIgRXz8VjFbfh8f8mfyMVt-Hx_yZ_ISR6pzt6j1tOqssNCwDfnM&_nc_ohc=oQeQeYLPRz8AX_n81Yh&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&oh=d87b3097c543a39067095bacfbeb004d&oe=609BF1DC',
        url: require('../../assets/songs/Hero.mp3'),
    },

    {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Advertising URL',
        ArtistName: 'Bethany Dilon',
        genre: 'Soft Rock',
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url:
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zmxv/react-native-sound-demo/master/advertising.mp3',
    },

    {
        id: 9,
        title: 'Stronger',
        ArtistName: 'Bethany Dilon',
        genre: 'Country',
        isRequire: true,
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url: require('../../assets/songs/Stronger.mp3'),
    },

    {
        id: 10,
        title: 'Faded',
        ArtistName: 'Luchee',
        genre: 'Techno',
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url: 'https://github.com/ShivamJoker/sample-songs/raw/master/Faded.mp3',
    },

    {
        id: 11,
        title: 'Solo',
        ArtistName: 'Solo Cosmos',
        genre: 'Afrobeat',
        isRequire: true,
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url: 'https://github.com/ShivamJoker/sample-songs/raw/master/Solo.mp3',
    },

    {
        id: 12,
        title: 'Death Bed',
        ArtistName: 'Omowunmi feat Wizkid',
        genre: 'Afrocentric',
        picture: 'https://scontent-los2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-0/s640x640/169534769_1185223728571457_6192837830233317030_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_eui2=AeH2splO8pf4k-atqrUeWWApKjkWnAsELXsqORacCwQte9doNY5rNtBrWht-o_CYYR4&_nc_ohc=plbZA_Pv91EAX_quQhG&_nc_ht=scontent-los2-1.xx&tp=7&oh=abec7b3bd8ddc13b6c3c0c510a33d8dc&oe=60997696',
        url: 'https://github.com/ShivamJoker/sample-songs/raw/master/death%20bed.mp3',
    },
    
  ];

  export default songs;
```

Comment: What are the contents of: '../../SongData'; ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the content of SongData.js

Comment: I think you'll want to wrap renderHeader in useMemo or move it outside of the component it's in, so it doesn't re-render every time the parent does. Also, songs should be a list, then `const data = [songs]`, then `list: [data]` makes it a 3d array? I also noticed that Playerlist has its own copy of songs, ListProvider provides a copy of songs, and ListContext has a different handle to songs. The point of a context is to protect/manage a piece of state for you so don't let anything else access it outside of the context consumers.

Comment: Thanks @windowsill for your response. I updated my code as you pointed out, but still the list is not displaying.  In the renderItem, the list should display like I specified there.

Comment: `data.filter((item) => item.indexOf(str) > -1)` If data is a list of objects this will throw an error because Object.indexOf is not a function.

Comment: if you want to search only by the title you could use something like `data.filter((item) => item.title.indexOf(str) > -1)`